# Improperly return true

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Coderbyte Challenge 7

Can somebody please help?  The below function is supposed to check that ever letter in the string has a '+' and both sides and return true, and false when a letter is not bounded by a +.  But when I pass the string below through, it passes true, when it should be false, as the k doesn't have a + on the right hand side.  Thanks in advance.

```
str = '+f+++l+k=+'

alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
function SimpleSymbols(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase()
  for (i=0 ; i<str.length ; i++)  {

    if (alpha.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) > 0 && i === 0)  {
        return false 
    }
    else if (alpha.indexOf(str.charAt(str.length -1)) > 0) {
        return false 
    }
     else  if (alpha.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) > 0 && 
        (str.charAt(i-1) !== '+' || str.charAt(i+1) != '+')) {
         return false
    }
     else {return true}    
   }       
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your function will break the `for` loop every time at the first iteration. You only need to break the loop on the `false` branches. Then simply return `true` after the for loop (meaning it didn't exit with `false` up until that line.

Comment: Got it CyberDude!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate solution:

You can just make use of this logic:

Calculate the number of alphabets and number of alphabets with `+` on either side. If they're both equal, return `true` else `false`

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) {
   return str.match(/[a-z]/gi).length == str.match(/\+[a-z]\+/g).length
}
```

Comment: While this is a short and elegant solution, it doesn't answer the original question which was about the behavior of the pasted code. It did not ask for an alternative. :)

Comment: Hhahahaha!  Wowsers!  you did in 2 lines, what took me like 15 lines.  Nice!!  Thanks for your help Amit.

Comment: @Anthony glad you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this simple logic

```
str = '+f+++l+k++'

function SimpleSymbols(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase()
  for (i=0 ; i<str.length ; i++)  {
      if (str[i] === '+') {
          continue;
      }

      if (i === 0 || i === str.length - 1) {
          return false;
      }

      if (str[i - 1] === '+' && str[i].match(/[a-z]/) && str[i + 1] === '+') {
          i += 1;
          continue;
      } else {return false;}
  } 

  return true;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vaaem18/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If we started discussing alternatives although `Regex` solution is much shorter, a version with `string.split` is much more readable:

```
function SimpleSymbols(str){
     if(str.length === 0) return false;
     if(str[0] !== '+' || str[str.length-1] !== '+') return false;
     var subs = str.split('+');
     for(var i =0; i < subs.length; i++){
          if(subs.length > 1) return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```